# How to make the divs fill the remaining space without using float?

Tags: css, html, toggle, center

Here is my problem: I know that I can fill the remaining space with float, but in that case, I can't do it,because, I want to div.visible to stay in the center when the div.collapse is hidden. If I put the float:left, the div always stays left.

In the HTML, I put a random width to show what should be the "centering" effect. But, the grey (Image) div has a fixed width.

Maybe I took the wrong way from the start. If you have a better idea how to achieve this, I will be more than happy to know how and why!!

Here is the html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="visible">
    <p>image</p>
</div>
<div class="collapse">
    <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

the CSS

```
.container {
position:absolute;
background-color:#FFFF99;
width:400px;
height:100px;
text-align:center;}

.visible {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
width:250px;  /*fixed width*/
background-color:#CCCCCC;}

.collapse {
background-color:#FF99FF;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
width:50px; /*random width*/}
```

and the javascript

```
$('.visible').click(function () {
    $('.collapse').toggle("fast");
});
```

Also, I have another question, when the width is to large for div.collapse (because it would eventually have a min-width), the effect is not smooth with this little flash on the side. How I could make it so it goes smoothly to bottom when it is too large?

Many Thanks!!!

Comment: Please post your code and don't try to work around the SO jsfiddle+code requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="visible">
            <p>image</p>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse">
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    display:table;
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.visible, .collapse {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Juxge/5/)